# Biased bootstrap: is it okay to center the CI around the observed statistic?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, bootstrap, bias, diversity

This is similar to [Bootstrap: estimate is outside of confidence interval](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133864/bootstrap-estimate-is-outside-of-confidence-interval)

I have some data that represents counts of genotypes in a population. I
want to estimate genetic diversity using Shannon's index and also
generate a confidence interval using bootstrapping. I've noticed,
however, that the estimate via bootstrapping tends to be extremely
biased and results in a confidence interval that lies outside of my
observed statistic.

Below is an example.

```
# Shannon's index
H <- function(x){
  x <- x/sum(x)
  x <- -x * log(x, exp(1))
  return(sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))
}
# The version for bootstrapping
H.boot <- function(x, i){
  H(tabulate(x[i]))
}
```

Data generation

```
set.seed(5000)
X <- rmultinom(1, 100, prob = rep(1, 50))[, 1]
```

Calculation

```
H(X)

## [1] 3.67948

xi <- rep(1:length(X), X)
H.boot(xi)

## [1] 3.67948

library("boot")
types <- c("norm", "perc", "basic")
(boot.out <- boot::boot(xi, statistic = H.boot, R = 1000L))

## 
## CASE RESAMPLING BOOTSTRAP FOR CENSORED DATA
## 
## 
## Call:
## boot::boot(data = xi, statistic = H.boot, R = 1000)
## 
## 
## Bootstrap Statistics :
##     original     bias    std. error
## t1*  3.67948 -0.2456241  0.06363903
```

Generating the CIs with bias-correction

```
boot.ci(boot.out, type = types)

## BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
## Based on 1000 bootstrap replicates
## 
## CALL : 
## boot.ci(boot.out = boot.out, type = types)
## 
## Intervals : 
## Level      Normal              Basic              Percentile     
## 95%   ( 3.800,  4.050 )   ( 3.810,  4.051 )   ( 3.308,  3.549 )  
## Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
```

Assuming that the variance of *t* can be used for the variance of *t0*.

```
norm.ci(t0 = boot.out$t0, var.t0 = var(boot.out$t[, 1]))[-1]

## [1] 3.55475 3.80421
```

Would it be correct to report the CI centered around *t0*? Is there a
better way to generate the bootstrap?

Answer (score 16):

In the setup given by the OP the parameter of interest is the Shannon entropy 
$$\theta(\mathbf{p}) = - \sum_{i = 1}^{50} p_i \log p_i,$$
which is a function of the probability vector $\mathbf{p} \in \mathbb{R}^{50}$. 
The estimator based on $n$ samples ($n = 100$ in the simulation) is the plug-in estimator 
$$\hat{\theta}_n = \theta(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n) = - \sum_{i=1}^{50} \hat{p}_{n,i} \log \hat{p}_{n,i}.$$
The samples were generated using the uniform distribution for which the Shannon entropy is $\log(50) = 3.912.$ Since the Shannon entropy is maximized in the uniform distribution, the plug-in estimator *must be downward biased*. A simulation shows that $\mathrm{bias}(\hat{\theta}_{100}) \simeq -0.28$ whereas 
$\mathrm{bias}(\hat{\theta}_{500}) \simeq -0.05$. The plug-in estimator is consistent, but the $\Delta$-method does not apply for $\mathbf{p}$ being the uniform distribution, because the derivative of the Shannon entropy is 0. Thus for this particular choice of $\mathbf{p}$, confidence intervals based on asymptotic arguments are not obvious.

The percentile interval is based on the distribution of $\theta(\mathbf{p}_n^*)$ where $\mathbf{p}_n^*$ is the estimator obtained from  sampling $n$ observations from $\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n$. Specifically, it is the interval from the 2.5% quantile to the 97.5% quantile for the distribution of $\theta(\mathbf{p}_n^*)$. As the OP's bootstrap simulation shows,  $\theta(\mathbf{p}_n^*)$ is clearly also downward biased as an estimator of $\theta(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n)$, which results in the percentile interval being completely wrong.

For the basic (and normal) interval, the roles of the quantiles are interchanged. This implies that the interval does seem to be reasonable (it covers 3.912), though intervals extending beyond 3.912 are not logically meaningful. Moreover, I don't know if the basic interval will have the correct coverage. Its justification is based on the following approximate distributional identity:

$$\theta(\mathbf{p}_n^*) - \theta(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n) \overset{\mathcal{D}}{\simeq} \theta(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n) - \theta(\mathbf{p}),$$
which might be questionable for (relatively) small $n$ like $n = 100$.

The OP's last suggestion of a standard error based interval $\theta(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n) \pm 1.96\hat{\mathrm{se}}_n$ will *not* work either because of the large bias. It *might* work for a bias-corrected estimator, but then you first of all need correct standard errors for the bias-corrected estimator.

I would consider a likelihood interval based of the profile log-likelihood for $\theta(\mathbf{p})$. I'm afraid that I don't know any simple way to compute the profile log-likelihood for this example except that you need to maximize the log-likelihood over $\mathbf{p}$ for different fixed values of $\theta(\mathbf{p})$.

Comment: The bias problem with using the "plug-in" estimator for entropy has been appreciated for decades. [This paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0403192v3.pdf) analyzes less-biased estimates. A bias correction up to order $1/n$, which dates to 1955 (see eq. 4 of the linked paper), can be applied to the case presented by the OP. The correction is 0.245, almost identical to the bias identified by the bootstrap. Perhaps the bootstrap should be used here for estimating the entropy itself, not just its confidence limits.

Comment: @EdM this is very useful information. I did not know the literature on this particular bias problem. It could be really useful if you could turn the comment into an answer that explains the bias correction and how it could be used with bootstrapping, say, to obtain confidence intervals.

Comment: I didn't know this literature either, until this question and your answer came up. Which is somewhat embarrassing, since Shannon entropy is often used as a measure in my area of biomedical science. I'll see what I can put together as an additional answer.

Comment: I apologize if I come off as a bit naive, but I noticed that if I set up the bootstrap to sample $n^2$ samples from a multinomial distribution where the probabilities are the observed proportions, the bias and the CI was reduced. Would increasing the number of samples used for the bootstrap be a method for addressing this?

Comment: Increasing the number of bootstrap samples will not really help. It has to be large enough so that you can reliable estimate the quantities of interest for the distribution of $\theta(\mathbf{p}_n^*)$, say, but otherwise increasing the number of bootstrap samples will not remove the bias or make the confidence any more appropriate.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not talking about increasing the number of bootstraps, but rather increasing the sample size per bootstrap replicate, so instead of drawing 100 samples with replacement, it draws 10000 samples with replacement. When I use this approach, the bias is about -0.04 and the confidence intervals encapsulate the data, but never go over 3.912. This is the function I used: `my_sampler <- function(x, mle = NULL){n <- length(x); rmultinom(1, n*n, tabulate(x)/n)}`. Are the CIs obtained from this method just as silly and meaningless?

Comment: Sorry ZNK, I misunderstood your question. If you increase the sample size $n$, the bias will be smaller, yes! The estimator is consistent. Precisely for the uniform distribution I would be somewhat sceptical about the actual coverage of the confidence intervals even for large $n$ for the reasons I described in the answer. For all other distributions the CLT applies, and the different methods will produce asymptotically correct coverage for $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 13):

As the answer by @NRH points out, the problem is not that the bootstrapping gave a biased result. It's that the simple "plug in" estimate of the Shannon entropy, based on data from a sample, is biased downward from the true population value.

This problem was recognized in the 1950s, within a few years of the definition of this index. [This paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0403192v3.pdf) discusses the underlying issues, with references to associated literature.

The problem arises from the nonlinear relation of the individual probabilities to this entropy measure. In this case, the observed genotype fraction for gene *i* in sample *n*, $\hat{p}_{n,i}$, is an unbiased estimator of the true probability, $p_{n,i}$. But when that observed value is applied to the "plug in" formula for entropy over M genes:

$$\hat{\theta}_n = \theta(\hat{\mathbf{p}}_n) = - \sum_{i=1}^{M} \hat{p}_{n,i} \log \hat{p}_{n,i}.$$

the non-linear relation means that the resulting value is a biased under-estimate of the true genetic diversity.

The bias depends on the number of genes, $M$ and the number of observations, $N$. To first order, the plug-in estimate will be lower than the true entropy by an amount $(M -1)/2N$. Higher order corrections are evaluated in the paper linked above.

There are packages in R that deal with this issue. The `simboot` package in particular has a function `estShannonf` that makes these bias corrections, and a function `sbdiv` for calculating confidence intervals. It will be better to use such established open-source tools for your analysis rather than try to start over from scratch.

Comment: So the estimator in and of itself is erroneous due to sample size? The `simboot` package looks promising, but doesn't seem suited for my purposes as it need a control sample to estimate confidence intervals.

Comment: "Erroneous" isn't quite right; the estimator is "biased" in that its expected value is not the same as the actual population value. That doesn't mean it's "erroneous"; biased estimators can be useful, as illustrated by the [bias-variance tradeoff](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4284/intuitive-explanation-of-the-bias-variance-tradeoff)  in selecting estimators. If `simboot` doesn't meet your needs, Google "shannon entropy bias r" for links to other R packages like `entropy`, `entropart`, and `EntropyEstimation`.

Comment: There are additional issues arising from the fact that some genotypes present in the population are likely to be missed in any particular sample. Some of the population- and ecology-based R packages appear to have ways to deal with this problem.