# Confidence interval not including the actual difference of the means

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, p-value, group-differences

I have used statsmodel in python to compare the means between a control and test group. The difference of the means is 29 and I get a low p-value making my results statistically significant. The 95% confidence interval is [18, 25] which does not include 0 but also doesnt include my actual difference which is 29. Is there something wrong with these results or can I assume that the 29 value just happened to be in the 5% of the times that is outside the CI?

Comment: How did you calculate the confidence interval and the difference in means? A coding error sounds like the likely culprit.

Comment: I just used this code for the confidence intervals https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.CompareMeans.html for the difference in means I just did the mean of each group and subtracted

Comment: Please provide the specific code you used, and if possible show density plots or histograms of all the values for the 2 groups. Are there any large outliers in one or the other of the groups?

Comment: Are these results impossible to happen?

Comment: can you include the code?

Comment: In bootstrapping, for example, bias in the estimates of the quantity of interest can lead to apparent [confidence intervals that don't include the mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/156235/28500). That seems highly unlikely to be the case in what you describe, but without further details on the code and the data I would hesitate to say "impossible."